# How do I disable warning 4355 globally in MSVC project?

Tags: visual-c++, warnings, pragma, visual-studio-2010

I want to disable warning 4355 globally in my MSVC C++ project. One solution would be to write

```
#pragma warning(default:4355)
```

in some prefix.h

and then `#include prefix.h` into all source files. But is it possible to disable this warning in project options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu: Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - C/C++ - Advanced - Disable Specific Warnings. Type 4355.

If you need to disable several warnings, use semi-colon delimiter.